# In the Python C API, if the second argument is not set how can I default to the value of the first?

Tags: python, c, cpython, python-c-api

I have an x, y parameters.  Using the python C API, how can I default y to the value of x if y is None.

The python equivalent is:

```
def scale(x: float, y:Optional[float]=None):
    if y is None:
       y = x

    c_scale_api(x, y)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just check it against `Py_None`.

```cpp
static PyObject* scale(PyObject* self, PyObject* args) {
    PyObject* input2 = Py_None; // initialize to None
    double input1d, input2d;
    if (!PyArg_ParseTuple(args, "d|O", &input1d, &input2)) {
        return NULL;
    }
    if (input2 == Py_None)
    {
        input2d = input1d;
    }
    else 
    {
        input2d = PyFloat_AsDouble(input2);
    }
    return PyFloat_FromDouble(input2d);
}
```

this will return the value of the second argument for you to check.

Comment: Thanks, some of this API is certainly a bit different to what's on the plain python side.

Comment: just a small note, this code checks that the second argument is None, but if the user passed in 1 argument you have to check its size with `int argc = PyTuple_GET_SIZE(args)`, the above code tries to decrypt exactly two arguments, it will throw an error if the user passed only 1 argument.

Comment: Ah, maybe I should be checking the size ?

One thing I was considering was checking for
`PyArg_ParseTuple(args, "dd", &input1, &input2)`

And then
`PyArg_ParseTuple(args, "d", &input1)`

But I wasn't sure if it's idiomatic.

Comment: i have editted the code with the correct way to check for two arguments.

Comment: @StuartAxon: At the C level, if `NaN` isn't a valid argument, you might use that as the empty argument initializer, then use `"d|d"` and detect a failure to pass the second argument by checking for `NaN` (which fits in a C `double` where `None` doesn't). It does change the API from the Python version, so users can't explicitly pass `None` and have it work, and it would behave as the Python function defined like `def scale(x: float, y:float=math.nan):`

Comment: @AhmedAEK: If you're going to use `PyArg_ParseTuple`, you should at least use the `d` format code for the non-optional argument and save having to store and manually convert the `PyFloat` to a `double` manually. Alternatively, keep it as is, but get rid of `PyArg_ParseTuple` (higher overhead due to parsing the format string each time) and replace it with `PyArg_UnpackTuple(args, "scale", 1, 2, &input1, &input2)` which is a lower overhead approach for unpacking the `tuple` directly without parsing the arguments (which `O` wasn't doing anyway).

Comment: @ShadowRanger that's a nice use of NaN, makes this more compact.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `|` to state that some arguments are optional when parsing the arg tuple. You must ensure that any arguments after the `|` always have a value before you use them. That is, `PyArg_ParseTuple` will leave the variables untouched if the argument was not present. Usually, that means you should assign the default values before you call `PyArg_ParseTuple`. However, because of your requirement, we can just check how many parameters we actually got, and then assign to `y` if only 1 argument was given.

This code will make the second argument optional, but is not fully equivalent to the python function. That is `None` is not a valid value for the second argument. So `scale(1, 2)` and `scale(1)` are both fine, but `scale(1, None)`  would fail.

```c
static PyObject*
scale(PyObject* self, PyObject* args) // type: METH_VARARGS
{
    double x;
    double y;
    if (!PyArg_ParseTuple(args, "d|d", &x, &y)) {
        return NULL;
    }
    if (PyTuple_GET_SIZE(args) == 1) {
        y = x;
    }
    return PyFloat_FromDouble(x + y);
}
```

For a fully equivalent C function try the following. Now things like `scale(x=1, y=None)` will work as well.

```c
static PyObject* 
scale(PyObject* self, PyObject* args, PyObject* kwargs) // type: METH_VARARGS | METH_KEYWORDS
{
    static char* keywords[] = { "x", "y", NULL };

    double x;
    double y;
    PyObject* y_obj;

    if (
        !PyArg_ParseTupleAndKeywords(
            args, kwargs, "d|O:scale", keywords, &x, &y_obj
        )
     ) {
        return NULL;
    }
    if (y_obj == Py_None) {
        y = x;
    } else if (PyFloat_Check(y_obj)) {
        y = PyFloat_AS_DOUBLE(y_obj);
    } else if (PyLong_Check(y_obj)) {
        y = PyLong_AS_LONG(y_obj);
    } else {
        PyErr_SetString(PyExc_TypeError, "y must be float | int | None");
        return NULL;
    }

    return PyFloat_FromDouble(x + y);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, "PyArg_ParseTuple will leave the variables untouched if the argument was not present."  this detail is really useful.